# django url-tag and decorated urls

Tags: python, django, django-templates

I'm writing a small blog-app and want its entries to be accessible via a combination of the title-name and the id.

```
Expression:    ^blog/([\d\w\-_]+)\-(\d+)/$
Example URL:   localhost:8000/blog/django-is-awesome-231/
```

The first part is generated by converting the blog-entries' title all to lowercase and replace spaces and special characters with `-`.

I was wondering how I can reverse such an URL from an entry.

```
{% for entry in entries %}
  <li><a href="{% url 'blog.views.display', entry.title entry.id %}">{{ entry.title }}</a></li>
{% endfor %}
```

But it tells me that no reverse match was found.

Thanks,

---

I just tried it this way:

```
def get_mangled_name(self):
    """ Returns the mangled name of the entry. """
    title = self.title.lower().replace(' ', '-')
    title = ''.join(filter(lambda x: x in string.letters, title))
    if title.endswith('-'):
        title = title[:1]
    return '%s-%d' % (title, self.id)


<li><a href="{% url 'blog.views.display' entry.get_mangled_name %}">{{ entry.title }}</a></li>
```

But it didn't work either.

Comment: You may want to lake a look at [get_absolute_url](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/instances/?from=olddocs#get-absolute-url) for the canonical URL of an object. That way you can format the url the way you want and just call `href="{{ entry.get_absolute_url }}"` from your template

Comment: There is a comma in your reverse, remove that and try

Answer (score 3):

There's a `slugify` template filter that will convert a title into a slug. So, you could write your template code like:

```
{% url 'blog.views.display', entry.title|slugify entry.id %}
```

However, any time you're dealing with slugs, you should actually have a `slug` field on your model to store the value permanently. At the very least, you should probably take  César's advice and do this in `get_absolute_url` instead.